# Record is getting updated but I am still getting this error in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I am trying to update the existing records in the MongoDB and records update are being reflected correctly, but in the console, I still see these warnings and errors:

```
{"name":"Bruce","number":"22222","date":"2020-12-18T20:08:45.446Z","id":"5fdd0c4d72a07e5d0c63c056"}
****  { _id: 5fdd0c4d72a07e5d0c63c056,
  name: 'Bruce',
  number: '22222',
  date: 2020-12-19T06:29:29.022Z,
  __v: 0 }
// ^------- this is the record body sent from the frontend and it's being updated correctly.

// but I still get this following  errors:

error:  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]
PUT /api/persons/5fdd0c4d72a07e5d0c63c056 402 99 - 116.533 ms {"name":"Bruce","number":"22222","date":"2020-12-18T20:08:45.446Z","id":"5fdd0c4d72a07e5d0c63c056"}
(node:8288) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: 
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\fsopen_revision\phonebook\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\fsopen_revision\phonebook\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at Contact.findByIdAndUpdate.then.catch (E:\fsopen_revision\phonebook\server\index.js:136:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:8288) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a 
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Code is used to perform Update:

```js
app.put("/api/persons/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  const id = Object(req.params.id);
  const body = req.body;

  const newPerson = {
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number,
    date: new Date(),
  };

  Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(id, newPerson, {
    new: true,
  })
    .then((updatedContact) => {
      console.log("**** ", updatedContact);
      return res.json(updatedContact).send({ message: "Updated" });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("error: ", e.name);
      res.send(402).json({ name: e.name });
    });
});
```

The frontend is working fine and data is also being updated correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message says: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

You can't send response two times. Either use `json()` method or `send()` method. Each of them construct headers for the response, send body (payload) and then ends sending response from the server.

```
// incorrect use of express api
res.json(updatedContact).send({ message: "Updated" });

// change to
res.json({ message: "Updated", contact: updatedContact });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sintax, first check if user id exists in DB, then findByIdAndUpdate with error and response handling:

```js
    updateUser: (req, res) => {
            
            const id = Object(req.params.id);
            const body = req.body;

            const newPerson = {
                name: body.name,
                number: body.number,
                date: new Date(),
            };

            Contact.findById(id, (err, res) => {
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error finding user'});        
            });      
            
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, newPerson, {new: true}, (err, updatedContact) => {
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error updating'});
                if(!userUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'user doesnt exists'});
                return res.status(200).send(contact: updatedContact);
            });
    }
```